# Why isnt my Paint Drawing on my Canvas? How Would I Draw a Checkerboard Based Upon a 2d Array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, awt

I am slightly new to Java and have messed around with Swing and AWT a few times, but I cannot currently get what I have to work. I have two classes,

Class GameController:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameController {
    Button giveButton;
    JFrame frame;

    public static void main () {
        GameController game = new GameController();
    }
    
    public GameController () {
        frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe!");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setBackground(Color.black);
        Panel buttons = new Panel();
        buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        giveButton = new Button ("GIVE UP");
        buttons.add(giveButton);
        frame.add(buttons);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and class Board:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Board extends Canvas {
    private int [][]playingGrid = new int[3][3];
    int boxheight = 30;
    int boxwidth = 30;
    
    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g){
        g.fillRect(10,20,30,40);
    }
}
```

I realize that the `paint` method I have now will not traverse my array and draw a 3x3 checkerboard like I want to do, but why isn't the `paint` method drawing anything when I execute? When I do fix this, how would I use a 2d array to make a checkerboard?

Comment: The first thing I would do, is read [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). Unless you need "as close to the metal" performance, I would not use `Canvas`, instead prefer `JPanel` and then override it's `paintComponent` method (don't forget to call it's super method first)

Comment: You also seem to have some confusion over the difference between AWT and Swing, these don't always place nice together, so be careful.

Comment: There are many examples of painting on this site.  All you have to do is search.  Specifying tags of java, swing, and possibly painting or graphics would narrow the search.

Comment: Hmm, based on your example code, you're not adding `Board` to anything

Comment: @MadProgrammer how would I add Board to it? Am I extending the wrong thing? Why doesnt the current Paint method apply to GameController?

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468805/tic-tac-toe-java-mouselistener/32468908#32468908), although, to be honest, I'd probably just use `GridLayout` and some buttons

Comment: @Andrew *"how would I add Board to it?"* - this is fundamental concept of Swing/AWT (and actually pretty much most UI frameworks).  Since you've already add a button, you already know how you should be adding other components, like `Board`.  Now, with respect, SO is not a tutorial or "teaching" site/forum.  There are better resources available to you, but AWT is WAY out of use, you'd be better with Swing or even JavaFX if you can

Comment: Unfortunately an int array alone is not going to help you.  You need something that can recognize some device to select a grid value and put either an X or O there.  You should probably experiment with mouse and button listeners to see how they work.  And not to be discouraging but this is not going to be all that easy for someone who is just learning to do graphics/painting.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Im a student looking to learn more, I apologize if I offended you or came across as unknowing, simply trying to learn what I did wrong here and how I would fix it, as well as anything else I can.

Comment: @Andrew No offence on my part. You could try looking at [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) and/or [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) depending on your point of reference